# Is good practice? Custom properties in akka configuration (application.conf)

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe, typesafe-config, hocon

I wrote akka application in scala, application related properties also I kept it in `application.conf` along with akka config. I find it is logical place to keep properties.

If it is not good practice I would like to know reasoning behind it,
for example one of my property is `akka.remote.receivers = [akka.ssl.tcp://remote-system@localhost:2222/user/receiver1]`

*How am I loading the properties?*

- Default properties I put it in `reference.conf` which exists in `main/resources`
- `application.conf` loaded with fallback `default.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good to have a `default.conf` config as fallback along with your `application.conf` which is specific to deployment enviroments/machines.

Your `reference.conf` should have all the library (akka or any other library) defaults. 
Then your `default.conf` should have the application defaults (including defaults needed for business usecases if any). Your `application.conf` should override only needed properties from `default.conf` and `reference.conf`.

Also I believe that your `default.conf` should not override any `reference.conf` properties. Any overriding should be done in `application.conf` only. This helps make sure that you have only 1 place of overrides and you don't have to go through multiple places to see which conf overrides what.

**Finally and most importantly:**

> Maintain consistency across apps/services/teams

In case you have multiple apps then make sure that you follow the decided process for all of them. It won't matter too much if you choose a bad way of using configs, but if you are in-consistent across your apps/services then its going to be a pain.

Comment: So you are concluding that custom properties in `application.conf` is not a bad idea, isn't it?

Comment: @SeetaRamayyaVadali :Yes exactly, I think that is one of the roles of application.conf. I believe we just be consistent in our decided approach.